# I don't want to see 'no file chosen' for a file input field

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way where i can stop "`no file chosen`" for input type file.

```
<input type="file" id="field-id" name="html" />
```

Comment: See: [How can I remove the “No file chosen” tooltip from a file input in Chrome?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14200185/1955615

Comment: See my answer to: [How can I remove the “No file chosen” tooltip from a file input in Chrome?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14200185/1955615

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the "No file chosen" tooltip from a file input in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome)

Answer (score 17):

Simplest (and reliable as far as I know) hack I've found is to set the initial font color to transparent to hide the "no file chosen" text, and then change the font color to something visible on change.

Voilá:

```
<input type="file" style="color:transparent;" onchange="this.style.color = 'black';"/>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can't get rid of the 'no file chosen' entirely, but you can change the text to something that makes sense by setting the title.

```
<input type="file" title="foo">
```

will display "foo" on mouseover instead of "no file chosen"

unfortunately,

```
<input type="file" title="">
```

doesn't work like you might hope.

Comment: <input type="file" title=" "> empty space will do the trick ;)

Comment: @Monicka If space is assigned to title attribute, on hover, it will show box with that space. It confuses user as if something is missing.

Answer (score 8):

For Chrome browsers you can use such trick:

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="html" style="width: 90px;" onchange="this.style.width = '100%';" />
```

Meaning setting fixed width that will show only the button then after change change it back to 100% so the file name is displayed.

Comment: What about displaying the button in other languages? 90px will not always be correct.

Comment: @jose as far as I could see, browsers won't expose the width of the button, just the total width of the whole input control - my way will work for website used by audience having the same language for better flexibility, custom control (as mentioned by alex) is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

```
<style type="text/css">
#inputcontainer {
    background:url("http://phpfileuploader.com/images/upload.png") no-repeat;
    height:50px;
    width:250px;
}

input[type="file"]{
    opacity:0;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
}
</style>
<div id="inputcontainer">
    <input type="file" onchange="document.getElementById('file-path').value = this.value.split('\\')[this.value.split('\\').length-1];"/>
    <input type="text" id="file-path"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you'd need to [create a custom control](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom).

Answer (score 3):

Seems ridiculous for the easiness but for me was enough:

```
input[type='file'] {
  width: 95px;
 }
```

Tested on Chrome 20, Safari 5.1.7 and IE 9.

Note: in IE9 is a little weird because left a mini input_text area.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code in the `mouseover` event

```
jQuery('input').attr('title', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old post, I think that this answer will be helpful to someone that wishes to do something similar. I wanted a button to insert an image from a mobile device's camera but I didn't want the ugly button "[Choose file] No file selected... " rubbish.

I wanted a button:

- that I could customize e.g. have a image button
- a user would click it and it would ask them for some file input
- use input and post to a server

What I did

1. create a button element

   - with an `onclick="someFunction()"` and some `id="some_id"`
   - an `img` tag with `src="someimage"` - to display an image rather than some text
2. create a input element

   - with `type="file" style"display: none" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="hidden_input"`
3. JavaScript

   - When I click the button, it will fire the `clickHiddenInput()` function that will execute the `click` event of the element you choose

     ```
     function clickHiddenInput() {
         document.getElementById("hidden_input").click();
     }

     document.getElementById("hidden_input").addEventListener('change', readFile, false);

     function readFile(evt) {

         if (!(evt.target.files.length < 1)) {

             var data = new FormData();

             var files = evt.target.files;
             var file = files[0];

             data.append("hidden_input", file);

             // do some stuff with the file
         }
     }
     ```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="file" title=" "/>
```

Be careful about the white space - it is important because title="" does not work.

Comment: Changing title does nothing with the text at least in my case

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the width settings, but it doesn't work in firefox. if you have a solid consistent background, you can just set the color to be the same as the background. I have a white background so I just:

```
input.remove-no-file-chosen
{
   width: 90px;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=file]{
       opacity:0;
}
```

Then you can design your box whatever style you want. If you click the div it will open the file explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

2021_11_17 in Chrome version 96.x will working. You only need CSS.

```
<input type="file" style="width:70px">
```

It's will hidden Text and cut width. You can mix more better with example:

```
<input type="file" style="width:70px;color:transparent">
```

It's will hidden Text, cut Width, Transparent text in other Browser.