# How can I remove the "No file chosen" tooltip from a file input in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I would like to remove the "No file chosen" tooltip from a file input in Google Chrome (I see that no tooltip is displayed in Firefox).

Please notice that I'm talking not about the text inside the input field, but about the tooltip that appears when you move the mouse over the input.

I've tried this with no luck:

```
$('#myFileInput').attr('title', '');
```

Comment: Maybe try to add space in the attribute value: attr('title', ' '). The tooltip will be still visible, but with empty content.

Comment: check my answer. use 'title': 'space'

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25825731/1323461

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is a native part of the *webkit* browsers and you cannot remove it. You should think about a hacky solution like *covering* or *hiding* the file inputs.

A *hacky* solution:

```
input[type='file'] {
  opacity:0    
}
```

```
<div>
    <input type='file'/>
    <span id='val'></span>
    <span id='button'>Select File</span>
</div>
```

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
})

$("input[type='file']").change(function(){
   $('#val').text(this.value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''))
})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8qN2/)**

Comment: Wow, that's bad news... Is there any documentation available that mentions this issue (I mean, te fact that you cannot remove that tooltip)?

Comment: @antur123 “No file chosen” like browser's back and forth button is not a part of the DOM, JavaScript has no access to them, for this reason I don't think there is a documentation about this issue.

Comment: Tooltip is still displayed, when you hover over the bottom edge of the input. "Opacity: 0" doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Webars I have mentioned hacky, not bullet-proof.

Comment: I understand. I'm looking for any solution, but no luck. :( Besides, browsers may block file dialog. So click on #button to open input:file - is a bad idea...

Comment: Just tested your website in Chrome 24 (latest). As you can see, tooltip is displayed. http://screencast.com/t/75uHC6YyuGhO

Comment: the tooltip is still displayed

Comment: @NisanthSojan So make it better, it was just an example.

Comment: One of the cleanest hack I have seen. Hopefully it will work in all browsers like IE9+, FF, Safari. Runs perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: I think there is simple solution. Check my answer below. I don't see anything simple than that. Also it works in all browsers.

Comment: Hey, if you want to hide the "No file choosen" tooltip: use "display:none" style and then use click function when tap the button.

Comment: it's still says 'no file choosen' in your fiddle example

Comment: You can hide with style: style='width: 0;overflow: hidden;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);display: inline;position: absolute;'

Answer (score 81):

The default tooltip can be edited by using the title attribute

```
<input type='file' title="your text" />
```

But if you try to remove this tooltip

```
<input type='file' title=""/>
```

This won't work. Here is my little trick to work this, try title with a space. It will work.:)

```
<input type='file' title=" "/>
```

Comment: Works in Chromium Version 44.0.2403.89 and has no side-effects in version 40.0.3! Great input @simon

Comment: but your custom title will show up even after choosing files.

Comment: I have integrated this solution with a binding engine (aureliajs, angular, ...) and this works very very fine to compute proper message and show to user.

Comment: This solution doesn't work on Chrome

Comment: I just tried this in Chrome 115. A tooltip is still shown, it just doesn't have any text in it. This is not a good look.

Answer (score 74):

For me, I just wanted the text to be invisible and still use the native browser button.

```
input[type='file'] {
  color: transparent;
}
```

I like all of undefined's suggestions but I had a different use case, hope this helps someone in the same situation.

Comment: Didn't take away the "no file chosen" for me.

Comment: this gets rid of the "no file chosen" for me

Comment: @MEM, which browser are you on?  This is working for me on Chrome (with some modifications because I don't just want the text to disappear).

Comment: This is the best answer for 2020. Setting opacity to 0 makes the whole element invisible.

Comment: This doesn't remove the tooltip that appears when you hover over the button, it just hides the text next to the button.

Comment: I used different selectors based on my needs. This is an odd fix. This doesn't change the color of the input button text like I would have thought it would do. When I look in the Chrome Debugger it doesn't show "No file chosen" anywhere. This must be a "feature" of the input type='file'. I could not get title=' ' to work (I had other text in it). It is ignored in my more recent version of Google Chrome. But  you color: transparent style works.

Answer (score 16):

Very easy, forget CSS targeting the input["type"] thing, it doesn't work for me. I don't know why. I got my solution in my HTML tag

```
<input type="file" style="color:transparent; width:70px;"/>
```

End of the problem

Answer (score 14):

I found a solution that is very easy, just set an empty string into the title attribute.

```
<input type="file" value="" title=" " />
```

Comment: You should just make title="" otherwise title=" " shows a blank tooltip.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable the tooltip setting a title with a space on webkit browsers like Chrome and an empty string on Firefox or IE (tested on Chrome 35, FF 29, IE 11, safari mobile)

```
$('input[type="file"]').attr('title', window.webkitURL ? ' ' : '');
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. 
I'd like to find a solution without wedkitURL because it's deprecated.

Comment: This answer is the only one that worked for me, just replaced the browser detection to the one provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Answer (score 5):

This one works for me (at least in Chrome and Firefox):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" title="&nbsp;"/>
```

Comment: The title's box (containing the non-breaking space character) still appears, however.

Comment: The title box does appear for me with an empty string on chrome.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tricky one. I could not find a way to select the 'no file chosen' element so I created a mask using the :after pseudo selector.

My solution also requires the use of the following pseudo selector to style the button:

```
::-webkit-file-upload-button
```

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/J8Wfx/1/

FYI: This will only work in webkit browsers.

P.S if anyone knows how to view webkit pseudo selectors like the one above in the webkit inspector please let me know

Comment: Did not work for me on chrome (the fiddle itself shows the no file chosen tooltip)

Answer (score 4):

Across all browsers and simple. this did it for me

```js
$(function () {
     $('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
          if ($(this).val() != "") {
                 $(this).css('color', '#333');
          }else{
                 $(this).css('color', 'transparent');
          }
     });
})
```

```css
input[type="file"]{
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="app_cvupload" class="fullwidth input rqd">
```

Comment: this is a great solution ! it worked great for me because after uploading the file, the file name would show. nice and thank you!

Comment: how is this removing the tooltip? I still see it

Answer (score 4):

All the answers here are totally overcomplicated, or otherwise just totally wrong.

html:

```html
<div>
    <input type="file" />
    <button>Select File</button>
</div>
```

css:

```css
input {
    display: none;
}
```

javascript:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('input').trigger('click'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/odfe34n8/

I created this fiddle, in the most simplistic way. Clicking the Select File button will bring up the file select menu. You could then stylize the button any way you wanted. Basically, all you need to do is hide the file input, and trigger a synthetic click on it when you click another button. I spot tested this on IE 9, FF, and Chrome, and they all work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap  with  and make  invisible.
Work in Chrome, Safari && FF.

```css
label { 
  padding: 5px;
  background: silver;
}
label > input[type=file] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="file">
  select file
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to customise the control quite a lot to achieve this.

Please follow the guide at: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: I was going to post this, plus that there is a JQuery plugin that does a sort of similar thing http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_custom_file_input_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/

Comment: @RyanMcDonough, I can't see any tips about hiding the tooltip in the link you provided, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Apologies, I should of clarified. As there is no way to hide that tooltip you will need to customise the input form control to achieve a similar result. In a sense hacking the original control.

Comment: @Dreen, I can see the "No file chosen" tooltip in the link you provided as well, it does not solve the problem...

Answer (score 3):

Even you set opacity to zero, the tooltip will appear. Try `visibility:hidden` on the element. It is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me!

```
input[type="file"]{
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

Then, you can use different kind of styles such as `width`, `height` or other properties in order to create your own input file.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to avoid using unnecessary javascript. You can take advantage of the label tag to expand the click target of the input like so:

```
<label>
  <input type="file" style="display: none;">
  <a>Open</a>
</label>
```

Even though input is hidden, the link still works as a click target for it, and you can style it however you want.

Answer (score 2):

Surprise to see no one mentioned about `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("input[type=file]").mouseover(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // This will disable the default behavior of browser
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `-webkit-appearance:` a go. Worth a try anyway.

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Directly you can't modify much about **input[type=file].**

Make input type file opacity:0 and try to place a relative element [div/span/button] over it with custom CSS

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/pvyVZ/8/

Answer (score 1):

```
style="color: transparent; width:110px"
```

This solution worked for me as below:

```html
<input class="ml-4"
       type="file"
       style="color: transparent; width:110px"
       ng2FileSelect
       [uploader]="uploader"
       multiple />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a width for yor element which will show only the button and will hide the "no file chosen".

Answer (score 0):

I look for good answer for this... and I found this:

First delete the 'no file chosen'

```
input[type="file"]{
font-size: 0px;
}
```

then work the button with the `-webkit-file-upload-button`, this way:

```
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-input-button{
font-size: 16px; /*normal size*/
}
```

hope this is what you were looking for, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Combining some of the suggestions above, using jQuery, here is what I did:

```
input[type='file'].unused {
  color: transparent;
}
```

And:

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type='file'].unused").click( function() {$(this).removeClass('unused')});
};
```

And put the class "unused" on your file inputs.  This is simple and works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, for me, is to wrap input [type="file"] in a  wrapper, and add some jquery code:

```js
$(function(){
 function readURL(input){
        if (input.files && input.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.onload = function (e){
                $('#uploadImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#image").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
});
```

```css
#image{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 75px;
 height: 35px;
}
#uploadImage{
 position: relative;
 top: 30px;
 left: 70px;
}
.button{
 position: relative;
 width: 75px;
 height: 35px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="form" >
 <div class="button">
  Upload<input type="file" id="image" />
     </div>
     <img id="uploadImage" src="#" alt="your image" width="350" height="300" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a hacky solution that totally removes "No file chosen" plus the extra space that is added after that text (in Chrome I get something like: 
"No file chosen                   ").

This was totally messing up my page alignment, so I really fought with it to find a solution. Inside the input tag's style attribute, setting "width" to the width of the button will eliminate the trailing text and spaces. Since the width of the button is not the same in all browsers (it's a little smaller in Firefox, for example), you'll also want to set the style's color to the same color as the background of the page (otherwise a stray "No" may show through). My input file tag looks like this:

```
<input style="float:left; **width:88px;** **color:#000000;**" type="file" id="fileInput" onclick="fileOpen()">
```

Comment: I didn't see the solution below until now, since it was so far down the page. In any case, I'm not going to delete my solution, since hopefully the style color information will be useful (it resolved the Firefox issue for me).

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit of a hack, but all I required was to set the color to transparent in the style sheet - inline would look like this style="color:transparent;".

Answer (score 0):

Best option to Hide the tooltip is combining the following properties :

1. On the input : `color:white;` (if the background is white to blind the color of text, if another color, use that color).
2. if there is any other element next to the input use `position: absolute;` to place the element above the tooltip *( be careful leave the button visible, hide just the tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that the 3 top did not work:

create your input element:

```
<input type='file' name='file' id='file' />
```

set style for the input element by it's Id to where it appears non-existent:

```
#file{ color: #ffffff; width: 0px; }
```

then create a new button infront of the original input, with onclick function to run javascript that clicks the original input:

```
<button onclick='clicker()'>BROWSE</button><input type='file' name='file' id='file' /> 
// can see the new button but not the original input:
```

Javascript:

```
function clicker(){ document.getElementById('file').click(); }
```

RESULT:

```js
function clicker(){
document.getElementById('file').click();
}
```

```css
#file{
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
FILE: <button onclick='clicker()'>BROWSE</button><input type='file' id='file'/>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about removing the tooltip. Make the capacity of file input into zero, put a div box above it with absolute position, so whenever you click on the div, the file input would prompt.

```
<div class="file_cover">Click to upload file</div>
<input type="file">
```

```
input[type='file'] {
  opacity: 0;
}
.file_cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a perfect solution for this

You can just add a label and link it to the input element

```
<label for="image__input">Choose a file</label>
<input type="file" id="image__input"/>
```

The functionality of the input element will be automatically applied to the label too

Then make the display of the input element as following to remove it

```
input[type='file'] {
   display: none;
}
```

After that you can style the label as you like

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelector("input[type=file]").setAttribute("title", "");
```