# Changing text beside upload field in Yii Framework

Tags: file-upload, yii

hopefully a quick question here, have not been able to find out the answer on google. Anyway I have the following File upload field.

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::form('', 'post', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'doc'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'doc'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'doc'); ?>
</div>
```

The question I have is how to change the default text? On the page in question the upload field comes up with "No file chosen" beside the button when the page loads. I wish to change this text, anyone tell me how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quick & dirty fix is this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'type',array('style'=>'width:100px;', 'onchange' => 'this.style.width = "100%";')); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment, that change the width alright but I need to change the text beside the box, not the width. Thanks.

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome

Comment: I see what that is trying to do alright, so I take it there is no easy way to just change the text lol?