# Javascript disable file input mouse over tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, input

I have a custom styled file upload button which is implemented by using the hack where you position a standard file input with opacity 0 positioned directly behind a custom button.  I would like the file inputs default "no file chosen" mouse over not to appear when the user mouses over my custom button.

Is there anyway to block that tooltip from appearing?

Furthermore, the file input seems to caption the mouse move events completely and they do not get triggered on my custom button, is there a way to prevent the file input from capturing mouse input like that?

Comment: I don't see any tooltip in ie/ff for file input. Are you sure it's not on the `title` attribute (for your custom button or the file input)? Did you consider using display:none or visibility:hidden instead of opacity:0? (I'm not entirely sure what you want). Could you make a demo? (jsfiddle or supply minimal html+css)

Comment: @Kraz If you look here in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/tzcsb/ just when you mouse over the file input there is a 'No file chosen' tooltip.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know Chrome's input were so... different. Here, [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome).

Comment: looks like there is no solution :/ thanks for the link