# Cross browser styling "choose file" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, file-upload

This is my code:

html:

```
<form>
    <input id = "file" type="file" />

    <div id="custom_button">custom button</div>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#custom_button").on("click", function () {
    $("#file").click();    
});
```

css:

```
#file {
    display: none;
}
```

But this works only in firefox and chrome, in safari and opera, at click on `custom button`, window  for file choosing is  not calling

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/J4GdN/

Qusetion: why this not works in  safari and opera? what is alternative, for making this in these browsers?

Comment: It works for me on Safari.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Some user agents disallow triggering click on input-file elements by js especially in css display:none. An alternative is this way:

HTML

```
<input id="file-element" type="file" name="my-file-upload" />
<div id="file-element-replacement">
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <img alt="custom upload" src="custom-upload.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#file-element {
    /* if opacity is 0 => some UAs interpret it like display:none */
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=1);
    -moz-opacity: 0.01;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.01;
    opacity: 0.01;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#file-element-replacement {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Make your input-file tranparent and simulate this with an input-text + image as a layer behind.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the standard `<label>` tag, setting the `for` attribute to the `id` of the `<input>`.

You can then hide the `<input>` and style the `<label>` as needed.

In my testing this works very well across browsers as it's standard functionality.

Comment: Well, Mamuz had a better idea. <Label>, in many browser, move focus to target element, but do not respond or pass other events to button (in some browsers do, just like in UI QT default is not the same as GTK). If you move your label bellow the button, you do what @Mamuz did, only replacing div with label (more elegant). I still wish to have a selector to button itself...