# Tooltip for fine-uploader uploadButton

Tags: tooltip, fine-uploader

I'm trying to change the tooltip for the fine-uploader uploadButton, but have noticed two things.

  1. When no files are selected the tooltip reads "No files selected". Once I've selected a few files, the tool tip doesn't change, but still reads "No files selected".
  2. I've tried grep'ing for this "No files selected" text in fine-uploader source, but can't find it.

Can anyone tell me how I can change this tool-tip?

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
    <script src="fineuploader/jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>

    <script src="fineuploader/jquery.fineuploader-3.6.4.js"></script>

    <link href="fineuploader/fineuploader-3.6.4.css" rel="stylesheet">

        </head>
        <body>
    <div id="manual-fine-uploader"></div>
<div id="triggerUpload" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload now
</div>


    <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var manualuploader = $('#manual-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
      request: {
        endpoint: 'server/handleUploads'
      },
      autoUpload: false,
      text: {
        uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Files'
      }
    });

    $('#triggerUpload').click(function() {
      manualuploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the "No file chosen" tooltip from a file input in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome)

Comment: Quite possibly. If I view my page in Firefox the tooltip reads "No files selected". If I view it in Chrome it reads "No file chosen".

Comment: As the answer to that question states: "This is a native part of the webkit browsers and you cannot remove it." Of course, Chrome is not using webkit anymore (they're using Blink), and Firefox is using Gecko. That would explain why different browsers show different texts when you hover over the file `<input>` element.