# How could the default tooltip for a telerik RadUpload control be set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, telerik

When the user hovers over the `Telerik.Web.UI.RadUpload` input button a tooltip appears showing the current path of the file to be uploaded or a 'No file chosen' text.
AFAIK and from the [official documentation for that component](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-localizing-radupload.html), it is necessary to load the localization related content from a .resx file, but I need to set that info via codebehind because the application I'm working on loads localization data from a cache.
A different approach could be to use the event raised whenever the cursor gets over the input button but I couldn't find neither an event nor an specific control holding that text.

Is there any other option letting me to set the content for that tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't comment that the situation happens in Chrome, not in IE10. It seems that the problem is related to webkit and has nothing to do with telerik. So this problem is solved as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome) and [here](http://rishipant.com/?p=59). By solution I mean to *disable* the tooltip.