# Unexpected letters appear by file input in Mac OS X (Safari, Chrome)

Tags: django, macos, google-chrome, file-io, safari

Problem looks as presented below.(`N` displays in Chrome and `B` in Safari)
I use flash live preview.

```
 <td><input type="file" name="file" id="preview" accept="image/*, application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width: 95px;"
                {% if readonly or not creative.active %} disabled {% endif %}></td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The N is the start of a string that appears next to the control, it says `"No file chosen"`. I'm guessing B is the start of `"Browse for a file`, or something like that. If you remove your width temporarily you'll see the full text.

So now you know why that text is appearing. You probably don't want it there.
Here is a [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909242/27604) on styling this type of HTML element.

Comment: Thanks. Answer how to deal with it if somebody wants to hide it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome