# Hidden/styled file input working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: css, html, input

The following code to style / hide an input type file is working in all browsers but Chrome.

```
<h5>Artikelliste hochladen:</h5>
<label for="uploadSkus">
    <button class="btn" id="add-article-list">
        <i class="icon icon-folder-open"></i> Liste auswählen
    </button>
</label>
<input type="file"
       name="uploadSkus" id="uploadSkus"
       class="articles-upload" style="display: none;">
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7onjztj/) here.

I'm stuck on which minor detail is preventing Chrome from letting this work.

Tried playing arround with the `display: none;` without success. No errors or warnings in the console. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article: [How can I remove the "No file chosen" tooltip from a file input in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome)

```
<h5>Artikelliste hochladen:</h5>
<label for="uploadSkus">
   <button class="btn" id="add-article-list"><i class="icon icon-folder-open"></i> Liste auswählen</button>
</label>
<input type="file" name="uploadSkus" id="uploadSkus" class="articles-upload" style="display: none;">

$('#add-article-list').click(function(){
   $("#uploadSkus").trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hidden` attr

```
    <h5>Artikelliste hochladen:</h5>
    <label for="uploadSkus">
        <button class="btn" id="add-article-list"><i class="icon icon-folder-open"></i> Liste auswählen</button>
    </label>
    <input type="file" name="uploadSkus" id="uploadSkus" class="articles-upload" hidden>
```

Comment: check it here http://jsfiddle.net/L7onjztj/1/ it works for me on chrome what version of chrome do you have?

Comment: Most recent Version 36.0.1985.143 m

Comment: is the fiddle working on it because that s the same version i have and it s working

Comment: It does.. I tried with a different computer with same Chrome still no success

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the `display:none` style on the input, the label works fine in firefox but didn't work in chrome.

To keep the hidden effect I removed the `display:none` style and add `height: 0px; overflow: hidden;` on the input.