# FileReader API 'load' event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am currently working on a Unity Webgl project and I am new to javascript and web .

In my project the user have to be able to add pictures and videos to the the webgl player, picture works fine (thanks to gman's code on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183253/unity3d-upload-a-image-from-pc-memory-to-webgl-app?rq=1)). I use it as a base for my script. Of course I have changed the input accept to be able to get video (mp4 only). But I am getting some trouble.

I have read this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and all the doc I have found about javascript File, Blob, etc. But I didn't make it work. I believe there is something I don't understand with `FileReader` since the `console.log` on the `"load"` listener is never called, same for the `"onerror"` listener except when I click on cancel (from the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183253/unity3d-upload-a-image-from-pc-memory-to-webgl-app?rq=1)).

```
function getPic( evt ) {
    var file = document.querySelector( 'input[type=file]' ).files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener( "onload", function () {
        reader.readAsDataURL( file );
        console.log( reader.result );
    }, false );
    reader.addEventListener( "onerror", function ( error ) {
        console.log( "error" + error );
    }, false );
}
```

I have tried `onloadend` too but it don't work, since the `onload/onloadend` listener is never called my script print `"null"`. Is that a good beginning or is there a simpler way to get `video/image` from user computer ?

Comment: You may read more about FileReader Api from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FileReader.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) property contains a event handler executed when the 'load' event is fired, when content read (eg. readAsDataURL) is available

- the event listener should be listening for the ['load'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event instead of 'onload'

---

```
reader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {...
reader.onload = function() {...
```

reader.readAsDataURL(file) is being called inside the callback function

- move the line reader.readAsDataURL(file); outside the 'load' event callback function

---

```
reader.addEventListener("load", function(){
   console.log(reader.result);
}, false);

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3vk4u0fr/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ! I have tried it but it never go on the onload listener.

Comment: I have no console error, the filename is correct and I go through all the function without passing by onload.

Comment: It works great ! (reader.onload = function() ...) So I believe that I just have to ReadAsDataURL and use this.result. I will check that !