# How do i get rid of this text on my output?

Tags: html, input

I am learning html input types, i tried the file type but i dont like this text that says "no file chosen" at the end of the output. Is there anyway to get rid of it?
[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBWa0.png)
[here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqSIb.png)

I tried to look on w3 but that did not work. Is there any way using js or html to fix this?

Comment: That text is coming because you are using file type and that text is saying to choose file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove the "No file chosen" tooltip from a file input in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome)