# Change the "No file chosen":

Tags: html, button, file-upload, pug

I have a button "Choose file" as follows (I am using Jade but it should be the same as Html5):

```
 input(type='file', name='videoFile')
```

In the browser this shows a button with a text next to it "No file chosen". I would like to change the "No file chosen" text to something else, like "No video chosen" or "Choose a video please". I followed the first suggestions here:

[I don't want to see 'no file chosen' for a file input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927212/i-dont-want-to-see-no-file-chosen-for-a-file-input-field)

But doing this did not change the text:

```
 input(type='file', name='videoFile', title = "Choose a video please")
```

Can anybody help me figure out where the problem is?

Comment: find answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat I do not want to remove it, I want to change the text

Comment: Can't you remove the text, and put a placeholder label next to it?

Comment: There is a really tidy answer to this in another post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21842275/3653494

Comment: it is very possible: check out this quick solution -- includes other stuff, just scroll to bottom of CSS:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWBJX00JSQD7

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot change the default labels on buttons, they are hard-coded in  browsers (each browser rendering the buttons captions its own way). Check out this [button styling article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Comment: It's not the label on the button, is the "No file chosen" next to it. When I choose a file, it changes from No file chosen to fileName.something. So I believe it should be changeable.

Comment: @FranXh Not possible unless you change the css class property.

Answer (score 299):

Hide the input with css, add a label and assign it to input button. label will be clickable and when clicked, it will fire up the file dialog.

```
<input type="file" id="files" class="hidden"/>
<label for="files">Select file</label>
```

Then style the label as a button if you want.

Comment: This even works in IE9, where you can't hide the `file input` and click it from JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution, it even allows for an easy way to customize the field

Comment: Interesting html solution, but bad for usability. The user will always see "Select file" or equivalent, even after selecting a file.

Comment: You can hide the 'Select file' label after image.onLoad if you do not want user to upload more images.

Comment: There's a nice recent [article with demo that uses this technique](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/). +1

Comment: How do I show "selected file name" after selecting?

Comment: The only feature I see this omitting is the ability to drag and release a file into the input

Comment: So much better than other solutions online.

Comment: Simple, but work perfectly. Even it can be improved with this pen https://codepen.io/nopr/pen/rpsnd

Comment: another quick solution: just scroll to bottom of CSS: (pure css - no js or anything based on is person's answer)
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWBJX00JSQD7

Comment: This answer breaks the drag and drop functionality of a normal file input, how can this functionality be added back?

Comment: You may place a div around, or a div contains the label. You may style that div or label however you like and place other elements inside, like 'drag and drop here' title or even an image. That element can handle drag and drop events. Just make sure it has 'draggable' attribute. By adding listeners to that div or label, you finally get what dropped in the event data sent by ondrop event and pass it to functions which handle file input.

Comment: in HTML:
<label ondrop="myScript">
in JavaScript:
object.ondrop = function(){myScript};
or
object.addEventListener("drop", myScript);

Comment: Changed nothing

Comment: How do you make it tabbable i.e. accessible?

Answer (score 42):

Try this its just a trick

```
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="img" style="display:none;"/>
<label for="img">Click me to upload image</label>
```

**How it works**

It's very simple. the Label element uses the "for" tag to reference to a form's element by  id. In this case, we used "img" as the reference key between them. Once it is done, whenever you click on the label, it automatically trigger the form's element click event which is the file element click event in our case. We then make the file element invisible by using display:none and not visibility:hidden so that it doesn't create empty space.

Enjoy coding

Comment: It seems that dragging files doesn't work when you do this.

Comment: This is not accessible solution; elements with display:none are not presented to user through assistive technologies.

Answer (score 26):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDgRG/

See above link. I use css to hide the default text and use a label to show what I want:

```
<div><input type='file' title="Choose a video please" id="aa" onchange="pressed()"><label id="fileLabel">Choose file</label></div>

input[type=file]{
    width:90px;
    color:transparent;
}

window.pressed = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('aa');
    if(a.value == "")
    {
        fileLabel.innerHTML = "Choose file";
    }
    else
    {
        var theSplit = a.value.split('\\');
        fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
    }
};
```

Comment: The best solution because it uses native Javascript that then still displays the file name, which is valuable. Most of the other solutions in the post doesn't do that.

Answer (score 15):

Right, there is no way to remove this 'no file choosen', even if you have a list of pre-upload files.

Simplest solution I've found (and works on IE, FF, CR) is the following

1. Hide your input and add a 'files' button
2. then call the 'files' button and ask him to bind fileupload (I'm using JQuery in this example)

```js
$('.addfiles').on('click', function() { $('#fileupload').click();return false;});
```

```html
<button class="addfiles">Add Files</button>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple style='display: none;'>
```

It's done, works perfectly :)

Fred

Answer (score 11):

```js
$(function () {
     $('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
          if ($(this).val() != "") {
                 $(this).css('color', '#333');
          }else{
                 $(this).css('color', 'transparent');
          }
     });
})
```

```css
input[type="file"]{
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="app_cvupload" class="fullwidth input rqd">
```

Comment: This is working very effectively it will hide text near the file input.

Answer (score 9):

The following will remove the "No file chosen" text, but leave the "Choose file" pseudo-button intact. Unlike other techniques here, this should have minimal effect on accessibility.

```css
input[type='file'] { font-size: 0; }
::file-selector-button { font-size: initial; }
```

```html
<input type="file"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

using label with label text changed

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" class="hidden"/>
<label for="files" id="lable_file">Select file</label>
```

add jquery

```
<script>
     $("#files").change(function(){
        $("#lable_file").html($(this).val().split("\\").splice(-1,1)[0] || "Select file");     
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

But if you try to remove this tooltip

```
<input type='file' title=""/>
```

This wont work. Here is my little trick to work this, try title with a space. It will work.:)

```
<input type='file' title=" "/>
```

Comment: I tested in chrome and all browsers. It is working fine. Can you please test it and verify.

Comment: Tested again in Chrome, Safari, Firefox. It does not work.

Comment: I check in chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 it is working perfectly fine. Which version are you using?@PantsMagee

Comment: It just adds tooltip with text you set at `title` attribute, as I see

Answer (score 5):

**HTML**

```
  <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <label class="upload">
      <input name='Image' type="file"/>
    Upload Image
    </label>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="file"]
{
  display: none;
}
.fileUpload input.upload 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Note:** Btn btn-primary is a class of bootstrap button. However the button may look weired in position. Hope you can fix it by inline css.

Answer (score 5):

```css
input[type=file] {
      color: transparent !important;
  }
input[type=file]::before {
    content: "Attach Your CV: ";
    color: black;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

> 

please use, after if you want to display the text after the button

Answer (score 4):

```
 .vendor_logo_hide{
      display: inline !important;;
      color: transparent;
      width: 99px;
    }
    .vendor_logo{
      display: block !important;
      color: black;
      width: 100%; 
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // set text to select company logo 
  $("#Uploadfile").after("<span class='file_placeholder'>Select Company Logo</span>");
  // on change
  $('#Uploadfile').change(function() {
    //  show file name 
    if ($("#Uploadfile").val().length > 0) {
      $(".file_placeholder").empty();
      $('#Uploadfile').removeClass('vendor_logo_hide').addClass('vendor_logo');
      console.log($("#Uploadfile").val());
    } else {
      // show select company logo
      $('#Uploadfile').removeClass('vendor_logo').addClass('vendor_logo_hide');
      $("#Uploadfile").after("<span class='file_placeholder'>Select  Company Logo</span>");
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.vendor_logo_hide {
  display: inline !important;
  ;
  color: transparent;
  width: 99px;
}

.vendor_logo {
  display: block !important;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="vendor_logo_hide" name="v_logo" id='Uploadfile'>
<span class="fa fa-picture-o form-control-feedback"></span>

<div>
  <p>Here defualt no choose file is set to select company logo. if File is selected then it will displays file name</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How would i get the text "Select Company Logo" to display under the button and not on the right side??

Answer (score 3):

You can try it this way:

```
<div>
    <label for="user_audio" class="customform-control">Browse Computer</label>
    <input type='file' placeholder="Browse computer" id="user_audio"> <span id='val'></span>
 <span id='button'>Select File</span>
</div>
```

To show the selected file:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
})

$("input[type='file']").change(function () {
    $('#val').text(this.value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''))
    $('.customform-control').hide();
})
```

Thanks to @unlucky13 for getting selected file name

Here is working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eamrmoc7/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work

```
input(type='file', name='videoFile', value = "Choose a video please")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the width of the input. Around 90px

`<input type="file" style="width: 90px" />`

Comment: It's simple and working fine. Just width is 100px; :)

Answer (score 2):

if you what to makeover the native html input. the check this bellow above jsfiddle link. I have used labels and input and also boostrap 5 for ui

```css
.custom-file input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="input-group custom-file">
            <label class="input-group-text" for="file-name">Choose file</label>
            <label class="form-control d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center" for="file-name" >
                <span>Choose a video please</span>
                <div class="spinner-border text-dark spinner-border-sm ms-auto" ></div>
            </label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file-name" onchange="pressed()"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: While it has too much noise, it's still a good solution in case you're using bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="field-label" for="photo">Your photo</label>
    <input class="field-input" type="file" name="photo"  id="photo" value="photo" />
</div>
```

and the css

```
input[type="file"]
{ 
   color: transparent; 
   background-color: #F89406; 
   border: 2px solid #34495e; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 36px; 
   border-radius: 3px; 
}
```

Comment: input[type="file"]{
   color: transparent;
   background-color: #F89406;
    border: 2px solid #34495e;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to change the name for "no file choose to Select profile picture"

```
<input type='file'id="files" class="hidden"/>  
<label for="files">Select profile picture</label>
```

Comment: the button is gone.

Comment: this worked just fine for me. Button was gone but clicking the label open files open dialog and you can style to label to make it look like button. It got rid of the annoying "No File Chosen" text.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every trick but nothing seemed to work and just resulted in hiding the text with the CSS color property to #fff since my background was #fff. Here is the code  :

```
<input class="form-control upload_profile_pic" 
   type="file" 
   name="userfile" class="form-control" 
    style="color: #fff;">
```

or

```
input.form-control.upload_profile_pic {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot. you can using css to hide that label "No File Choosen"

```
input[type=file] {
    width: 93%;
}
```

Width can vary depending on your ui. above one worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

if you juts want to hide the **no file chosen** message on hover of input type file then just make it empty

```
<input title="" type="file">
```

Comment: The question seems pretty clear. They want to **change** the text **next** to it, not hide the text in the tooltip.

Answer (score -2):

I would use "button" instead of "label", hope this help someone.

This will just display a button, user clicked will popup file chooser, after file chose, automatically upload.

```
<button onclick='<%= "$(\"#" + FileUpload1.ClientID + "\").click(); return false;" %>'>The Text You Want</button>

<asp:FileUpload onchange="$('#btnUpload').click();" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" style="display: none;" />

<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" style="display: none;" />
```

Answer (score -2):

There's a good example (which includes file type validation) at:

https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/html/forms/file-examples/file-example.html

It's basically a fleshed-out version Amos' idea of using a button.

I tried several of the suggestions above with no success (but maybe that's me).

I'm re-purposing it to do an Excel file conversion using

```
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="excel_converts">Choose a spreadsheet to convert.</label>
      <input type="file" id="excel_converts" name="excel_converts" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" >
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
      <p>No spreadsheet currently selected for conversion</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: So this was downvoted why?  Perhaps because in a totally unrelated post I suggested that it was easy to do knee-jerk downvotes but much less easy to be constuctive?