# Struts 2: Change default messages on tags

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm working with Struts2, in this case I would like to customising my input tag message.
Basically change the "No file selected" by a new one.

[image]

Does anybody know how do it?

Comment: Do you use a validation in Struts2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a hard-coded message for the browser tag `file` and you cant change them directly . But you could do that using `css` or `jquery`.

sources here [How can I remove the "No file chosen" tooltip from a file input in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome) and [Change the "No file chosen":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001586/change-the-no-file-chosen)