# Center vertically text for file-input

Tags: html, css, file, input, user-input

[image]

I want to center vertically `No file chosen` text with the file `button`. How I can do that?

Comment: can i see your html & css code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the "No file chosen":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001586/change-the-no-file-chosen)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could put both the button and the text in a [flex-box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) by placing them inside a div with the flex-container class. Then style the `.flex-container` div with `align-items: center` in your css file. [Here's some more info](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-7), and here's a very basic example.

```css
.flex-container {

  align-items: center;

}

button {

height: 100px;
width: 100px;
font-size: large;

}

span {

  font-size: small;

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <button class='flex-item'>Big button</button>
  <span class='flex-item'>Tiny text</span>
</div>
```