# Translate "No file selected" - No JavaScript

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to translate or delete the "No file selected" etiquette from `<input type="file">` **without** JavaScript or similar.

In many stack overflow answer I found this solution but it doesn't work.

```html
<input type='file' title=" " />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Comment: @mx0 no, it doesn't. I don't want to customize the button but only the text outside it.

Comment: Please see: [question]:https://stackoverflow.com/q/5138719/18050127

Comment: If you only want to change the text, then this isn't possible. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001586/change-the-no-file-chosen

Comment: If I use `input[type=file] { color: transparent !important; }` the element continues to have the same width as before

Answer (score 0):

You can simply design its color:

```html
<input type='file' title="foobar" style="color: white;" />
```

Comment: the element continues to have the same width as before