# How to change no file chosen to a filename in Bootstrap using jQuery.?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, bootstrap-file-input

I am trying to set no file chosen in upload file to a filename . How to set no file chosen to a file name.
What I have tried is:

```
<input class="form-control" id="imgInp" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" name="img" required>
```

On load of a form , I am trying to set value of no file chosen to a filename

```
$('#imgInp').val('abcd.jpg');
```

[image: Output]

How to change no file chosen in file input?

Comment: This stackoverflow post can assist you with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001586/change-the-no-file-chosen

Comment: Im confused, the input isn't working or you just want to change the default text?

Comment: @Wayne I want to change default text " No File Chosen"

Answer (score 0):

## Easy Solution:

**Add placeholder**

```js
<input class="form-control" id="imgInp" placeholder="no file chosen" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" name="img" required>
```