# I want to change default text on "no file chosen" when we use input="file"

Tags: javascript, html, .net, css

[image: how to change the text "no file chosen" in this below image![][1]] .

how to change the "no file chosen" text in this image
 Please help to me. 
       thanks & regards
       chakri

Comment: possible duplicate of [I don't want to see 'no file chosen' for a file input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927212/i-dont-want-to-see-no-file-chosen-for-a-file-input-field)

Comment: @AdrianWragg OP wants to change the text not remove it.

Comment: @Mr_Green, [Erich Douglass' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9795887/464709) does apply, though.

Comment: @Mr_Green At least one answer to that question answers this one directly.

Comment: @ Adrian wragg . I want to replace the text in place of "no file choosen" to "no file"

Comment: @chakri Read the answers on the question mentioned. They will answer your question too.

Comment: use this `<input type="file" title="no file">`. It is in the duplicate post man. read the above comments again.

Comment: Also - if you're asking a question where an image is involved, it's worthwhile also cropping out the whitespace a bit.

Comment: @Mr_Green <input type="file" title="no file"> is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used CSS to hide the default text and used a label to show the new text. Have a look-
 http://jsfiddle.net/ZDgRG/

Choose file

```
input[type=file]{
    width:90px;
    color:transparent;
}

window.pressed = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('aa');
    if(a.value == "")
    {
        fileLabel.innerHTML = "Choose file";
    }
    else
    {
        var theSplit = a.value.split('\\');
        fileLabel.innerHTML = theSplit[theSplit.length-1];
    }
};
```