# How to change the placeholder for file input in Bootstrap 5+

Tags: bootstrap-5

How to change the placeholder for file input in Bootstrap 5+

[Need to replace "No File Chosen" in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmSXv.png)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770908/how-to-change-choose-file-text-using-bootstrap-5

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760800/i-want-to-change-default-text-on-no-file-chosen-when-we-use-input-file